# Test NG - console output in Eclipse is overwritten

Tags: eclipse, testng, rest-assured

whenever I run tests as TestNG, the report from tests is partial in Eclipse.
For example when the rest assure test is run, the report in console is overwritten. It is not appended and I have no clue why.
The following code logs request body and response body. If it is run I see first the request body which is immediately overwritten by response body.

```
@Test(priority = 1)
public void simplTest() {
    req.given().log().all().when().get().then().log().all();
}
```

Here is the content of TestNG.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="classes" verbose="5">
<parameter name="orders" value="endpoint1/s" />
<test thread-count="1" name="Test" parallel="none">
<classes>
  <class name="salesManagement.Orders.GetOrders"/>
</classes>
</test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Can anybody help me why it happens?

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `parallel` attribute from your `suite` block in your `testng.xml`.

This is causing problem in your case as request is executed in one thread and response is logged in some other thread which is overriding the console logs.

**EDIT:**

You can also increase the console limit by changing `console buffer size` or removing the limit totally by unchecking `limit console output` in Eclipse by navigating to `Window -> Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Console`.

[image]

Comment: It has not helped. I completely removed parallel attribute in both blocks and even removed thread-count.

Comment: Even here is an example which works... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eP0-r3wkpFs

Comment: Try running your test in terminal and check if you have same problem in terminal as well.

Comment: I know where is the problem. The JSON response is very excessive and long. So that is why it is cut. Are there any limits for messages in console in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Actually got it. The response was not rewritten, but due to the settings in Eclipse it was cut off. Sorry for bad post, feel free to rename it. I thought it was an issue with Rest Assured. The problem is that the response body was too excessive and that is why it has happened.

SOLUTION: In Eclipse - Window - Preferences - Run/Debug and unmark the Limit console output.

[image: Unmark Limit console output]